# Syntax error for catch block, works on one computer, but not on the other?

Tags: java, syntax, exception, syntax-error

This part of my code won't compile on my laptop, but it works just fine on my desktop. Am I missing something simple here? The only difference is that I'm using DR JAVA instead of eclipse. It gives me a syntax error saying Syntax error on token "|", . expected. This is on the catch line of code.

```
protected void done() {
         try {
          get();
         } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
          // do something with any exceptions here

         }
        }
```

Comment: That is an old new feature. The `|` within a `catch` expression is only part of the Java language since Java 7.

Comment: How do I fix that issue then?

Comment: You check if Dr Java is using an older version and switch it if possible.

Comment: @Remixt upgrade to Java 7 lol

Comment: OH, that is pretty apparent when I actually pay attention to your first comment. Sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with you syntax, this should work fine. This is an old error, that does not matter with java 7 or later versions.  Im guessing you are using DR JAVA on mac? JAVA DR on mac is not compatible with Java 7 or 8, thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: No, I'm not using a mac.

Comment: I upgraded my DR java application and it now gives me the error 1 error and 23 warnings found:
-------------
*** Error ***
-------------

Error: Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7